# How to get Gravity Forms form ID by it's name?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

The Gravity Forms API offers a way to get a form: https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#get-form but it only accepts the form ID. How do we get a particular form by its name?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that looks up a form by its name and returns the form object:

```
function gf_getFormByName($name) {
    $forms = GFAPI::get_forms();

    foreach ($forms as $key => $form) {
        if($form['title'] === $name){
            return $form;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Needless to say if you have multiple forms with the same name, it'll return the first one it finds.

Comment: _“Usage with GFAPI::get_form would be”_ … rather redundant; `get_forms` gets you the form objects already, so you could simply return _that_ directly from within the loop, once you found it, instead of passing the id into `get_form` again, which probably means yet another database query.

Comment: not as elegant as @Bhautik Nada's answer. RGFormsModel::get_form_id

Comment: @JJS RGFormsModel is deprecated.

Comment: @Max-S But GFFormsModel isn't

Answer (score 1):

```
$form_id = RGFormsModel::get_form_id( 'Form Name Goes Here...' );
```

Comment: RGFormsModel is deprecated.

Comment: As RGFormsModel is deprecated just use
`$form_id = GFFormsModel::get_form_id( 'Form Name Goes Here...' );`